# Is there a way to calculate a new column of a dataframe on base of values in a(nother) lookup table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lookup

Is it possible to calculate and add the results to an existing dataframe while the calculation bases on a lookup table with a different format?

More precise:

I have a comma separated file that I open and read in as pandas dataframe. The read-in dataframe contains 38 different data columns and an (while read in process created) additional index column over several thousand rows:

[image: eSection of dataframe "data"]

My lookup table contains values as base for a calculation.
As well, it is a comma separated file read in as pandas dataframe. It contains 24 rows and 6 columns and an additional  index column:

[image: Lookup table]

And here comes the calculation which I try to realize:
In a new column "M_A" I want to write the result of a calculation like this:

[image: Calculation formula]

while i stands for the according values of C00, C01, C02....C22, C23

While SP, FR, C00, C01, C02 [...] are a column part of the "data" dataframe,
PV, W and RC_A are part of the lookup table dataframe.
Common indexing parameter of the "data" and the "lookup" tables are values of the colums of C00, C01, C02 according to column "C" of the lookup table. Calculation values should be taken when data column C00, C01, C02... match lookup table row C00, C01, C02...

As iteration is not a recommended solution for datasets of this size I tried it without but do not find the right way as my lookup table has not the same length as my data table.

```
df_data['A_calc'] = ((df_data.T / (df_data.SF * df_data.SP)) * ((df_data.C00 * df_lookup.PV * df_lookup.W * df_lookup.RC_A) + (df_data.C01 * df_lookup.PV * df_lookup.W * df_lookup.RC_A) + (df_data.C02 * df_lookup.PV * df_lookup.W * df_lookup.RC_A)+ ...)
```

This leads to the Error message:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'PTU_Airdensity_recalc'

Is there a way to realize this in Python with Pandas df? Maybe even more elegant than mine which I choose to visualize what my intention is...

Any suggestions?

Thanks, Swawa

Comment: is PVi,Wi,RCAi, representing columns or rather values in the lookup data?

Comment: PVi,Wi,RCAi, is representing values in the lookup data from the specific row of C00, C01, C02... in the lookup table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for my understanding to apply the formula; for each  column Ci we multiply it with values PV[i], W[i],RC_A[i]  then sum over each result

```
result=0

for i in range(len(df_lookup)):
   result=result+(df_data[df_lookup.loc[i,"C"]]*df_lookup.PV.iloc[i] * 
   df_lookup.W.iloc[i] * df_lookup.RC_A.iloc[i])

#result is a  column

#then we multiply element wise

df_data['A_calc'] = ((df_data.T / (df_data.SF * df_data.SP))*multiply(result, axis="index")
```

Comment: this looks good -do I have to define "multiply" ? I get this Message:NameError: name 'multiply' is not defined

Comment: ah, sorry, multiply is defined in Numpy. Adding this to the impot list, there occurs no error concerning multiply

Comment: ... but an error message stays what I cant interprete:                                                                           TypeError: ufunc() missing 1 of 2required positional argument(s)

Comment: the error is thrown at the line of the calculation?

Comment: multiply is actually of the pandas , you're working with pandas DataFrame right?

Comment: "the error is thrown at the line of the calculation?"-> yes the error is thrown at the line of the loop calculation. I probabely have to write data into a new frame after each loop? otherwise any following loop will overwrite the result before.. And yes, I am using pandas... strange that gave an error; only when adding numpy to import this error was gone

Comment: TypeError: ufunc() missing 1 of 2required positional argument(s) , is throwed when you're using a fuction and you're not giving enough arguments , however  in the  loop we don't use it , I think

Comment: do you redo the loop and the second step multiple times?

Comment: no, the loop is performed only once, but each time the counter rises the results from the lap before are overwritten with the following ones: calculation values of C00 are overwritten by calculation values of C01 and so on.. And the second step is also performed once. there was an * instead of a point before multiply. this part is working now :-)

Comment: it's adding to it with each step of the loop not exactly overwriting it, cs each time you add the previous result to the new calculated ones. hope it's working for you ^^

Answer (score 0):

This version is working now. Thanks a lot to the help of Ran A!

```
result=0

for i in range(len(df_lookup)):
   result=result+(df_data[df_lookup.loc[i,"C"]]*df_lookup.PV.iloc[i] * 
   df_lookup.W.iloc[i] * df_lookup.RC_A.iloc[i])
   #result is a  column

#then we multiply element wise

df_data['A_calc'] = ((df_data.T / (df_data.SF * df_data.SP)).multiply(result, axis="index")
```

this line is working then with "." instead of "*".
But the loop I am still working on...